# Open multiple files and do analysis n(n-1)/2 combinations of each file with ruby script

Tags: ruby, file-io

I am doing comparative analysis. I have "x1,x2,....xn" number of files. I wish to use each file as single input element and process with my script as (x1 vs x2, x1 vs x3, .... x(n-1) vs xn). This will iterate n(n-1)/2 operations with n(n-1)/2 results.

Kindly help me to open "n" number of multiple files in iterative manner and production of results in n(n-1)/2 combinations.

The file name will differ randomly with suffix *.gbk

Comment: I just tried with multiple "open" in my script... But, I have 50 files . Sometime, it may go upto 100. Now, the script have 50 junk lines. I need some simple method to open multiple files at single time. Once file is opened, I can make combinations and results easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dir['name/of/the/directory/*.gbk'].combination(2) do |f1, f2|
   puts "file #{f1} vs file #{f2}"
end
```

Comment: This answer is interesting. But, "The file name will differ randomly with suffix *.gbk". Its not same all time.... and it will differ "n" times. The file names have to be understood automatically from folder :(.

Comment: I tried this method. The problem is "Dir['name/of/the/directory/*.gbk'] blah blah is working" and "s= 'name/of/the/directory/*.gbk' Dir[s] blah blah is not working". I am getting directory location from userinput :(

Comment: @Palani try chomp'ing the userinput.

Answer (score 0):

```
input = "name/of/the/directory/"
array_of_input_files = Array.new
Dir.foreach(input) do |f|
 if f =~ /gbk$/
  array_of_input_files.push(f)
 end
end

array_of_input_files.each_with_index do |inp1, index1|
  array_of_input_files.each_with_index do |inp2, index2|
    if index2 > index1
      puts "#{inp1} vs #{inp2}"
    end
  end
end
```

I tried this one and working good. Please comment this with better way of scripting for above method.